# Can I fully prevent SQL injection by PDO Prepared statement without bind_param?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am very new to PDO, sorry if you feel I am asking stupid question.
Normal and simple PDO Prepared statement without **Bind_param** :

```
$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$sql->execute(array($name));
$rows = $sql->fetchAll();
```

with **Bind_param** :

```
$sql->bind_param("s", $name); //s means the database expects a string
```

I heard people said : **"The protection comes from using bound parameters, not from using prepared statement"**. May I know what is **bound parameters**? **Bind_param** is **bound parameter**? If yes, then the normal and simple PDO Prepared statement without **Bind_param** CANNOT fully prevent SQL injection?

Comment: I have not used PDO myself, but I was pretty sure it was safe for (most) injections? And you are missing a quote in your prepare-statement.

Comment: Reason why PDO is safe is because it runs PDO::quote() function on any parameters that you pass. In your 1st code example, you passed an array of values to `execute` function. PDO will run the `quote` function and it will treat all parameters as **strings**. So yes, you are doing it right except you won't be able to write NULL values to your db (integers can be quoted and will be treated as such). Alternatively, you can **bind parameters manually** and tell the PDO how to treat those parameters - as integer, string or NULL (and special types for stored procedures such as IN / OUT / INOUT).

Comment: @N.B. care to learn the matter better?

Comment: @N.B, since pdo will treat all prarameters as strings, so bind_param("s", $name); is just an extra code which is useless...

Comment: Your `->bind_param("s", ...)` syntax belongs to `mysqli`, not `PDO`. (But same thing applies of course). It's true that you rely on SQL type coercion when passing all parameters via a single `->execute()` versus specifying the type explicitely. (Effect depends on the table scheme at question of course.)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - comments allow only 600 characters, I can't explain everything to detail so programming nazis like you can be satisfied. So please take your arrogant attitude somewhere else and learn how to behave before acting smart. Zac, you can use `PDOStatement::bindValue` method to explicitly bind parameters to the proper type.

Comment: @N.B. ok, in short - it doesn't use PDO::quote(). at least when in native mode. that's the whole point of native prepared statements - you don't have to quote anything. when it only emulate prepares - it does escaping though, like you said

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - what's the point in going to details such as these when the person asking the question is wondering **how** is that PDO is safe for preventing sql injection? You haven't mentioned those in your answer nor have you given any examples to back up your statements. How's it helping a person new to PDO? Native prepared statements, emulating prepares and so on, those sound like jibberish to someone who doesn't know a thing about them, of course I won't go such details trying to outline how something works in theory.

Comment: @N.B. it is not for the OP, it is for you, whose statement `PDO is safe is because it runs PDO::quote() function on any parameters` is not [entirely] true.

Comment: Oh, I also heard that emulating prepares is fake prepared statement... Can fake prepared statement prevent SQL injection fully? If it cannot, how do I avoid the fake prepared statement?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - aren't you nice, explaining it to, oh poor uknowledgeable me. Thank god we have a genuine Robin Hood to the rescue :) too bad you can't think out of the box tho.

Comment: `$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );` to avoid. However, emulated would serve you as well. The only thing you'll be unable to do is to bind LIMIT clause variables using execute().

Comment: do I really need to set emulate to false? If I don't set it, SQL injection will not be prevented?

Comment: It is okay, I found the answer at http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/?p=187#pdo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing it right. The bound parameters are the one declared in a "prepared statement" using ?. Then they are bound using execute() with their value as a parameter to be bound to the statement.

Comment: So bound parameters is not bind_param. So I can fully preventing SQL injection without using bind_param right?

Comment: Erm, bound parameters are bound through the action of binding. Bind parameters = bound parameters.

Comment: But yes, no need for that bind_param function.

Answer (score 5):

> The protection comes from using bound parameters, not from using prepared statement

Means it is not enough just to use `prepare()` but keep all variables in the query like this:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name ='$name'");
$sql->execute();
$rows = $sql->fetchAll();
```

Someone who said that meant "although *technically* you are using a prepared statement, you aren't *binding* variables to it". So it makes the query vulnerable all the same.

To be protected, you have to substitute all variables in the query with placeholders, and then bind them:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?");
$sql->bindParam(1, $name);
$sql->execute();
$rows = $sql->fetchAll();
```

However, PDO has a nice shorthand for binding, allowing you to avoid the repetitive calls to `bindParam()`/`bindValue()`, doing all these calls internally when you send variables into `execute()`:

```
$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$sql->execute(array($name));
$rows = $sql->fetchAll();
```

It does essentially the same binding as `bindParam()`/`bindValue()` does. **Thus your code is using binding and therefore safe**

Finally, **bind_param()** is actually a mysqli function that has nothing to do with PDO.

Answer (score 2):

That is true.

I have no expert information on this but from what I understand, the problem with SQL injection is that the SQL server receives a string and regards it as true. The server has no means of knowing if, for instance, the `DUMP` commands were made intentionally or not.

With bound parameters, you say to the SQL server "Hey look, this is the query, and I expect parameters here, here and there. Oh and btw, here are the values". This approach is different because SQL now knows the actual expression it has to execute and what the values are. This allows SQL to insert the values into the expression, without modifying the expression itself.

Answer (score 1):

OWASP gave me the same doubt, following their guidelines against SQL injection "[SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)" they say:

**Defense Option 1: Prepared Statements (with Parameterized Queries):**

- PHP – use PDO with strongly typed parameterized queries (using bindParam())

so it seems as if you should use bind_param() at all times. I don't use it because I converted thousands of vulnerable DAOs with an automated script and bind_param() would require me to hand edit them all.

I have yet to see examples of injection without bind_param() used, so I am confident it is not necessary.

Comment: There are no such examples. OWASP is a highly unreliable source. The page you are referring to is just an awful collection of rumors and superstitions.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right.

The **wrong** way:

```
$sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = '.$name); //WRONG WRONG HORRIBLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you DON`T have to bind parameters to make sure you are protected from SQL injection attacks. The manual tells us: "Also, calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by eliminating the need to manually quote and escape the parameters." - [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). Enough said.

Binding parameters is just a handy way of making your SQL query re-usable - you can bind anything to your 'placeholders' once you put them into your SQL query - a great example is here: [W3school example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

But once again, the job is done using `prepare` and `execute`.